# How to add n number of digits to a string with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to add a given number of zeros to a string so that the scalar $newstg below comes out to '1000'.

```
use strict;
my $number_of_zeros = 3;

my $newstg = '1';
$newstg = $newstg . sprintf("%0$number_of_zerosd\n",$subd); 
print "Subd: $newstg\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`x` repetition operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators).

```
my $number_of_zeros = 3;
print '1' . 0 x $number_of_zeros;
```

Comment: All the answers were good. This is what I used in my code. Not sure if any one answer was better than the rest.

Comment: @gatorreina in your case I would say that the one you find clearest is the best way. Readability in your code mostly trumps everything else.

Answer (score 6):

Use can use the `*` notation supported by `sprintf`/`printf` to use variables in your template.

```
$newstg .= sprintf("%0*d\n", $number_of_zeros, $subd);
#same as   sprintf("%03d\n", $subd);
```

Answer (score 2):

It will work fine if you change this line:

```
$newstg = $newstg . sprintf("%0$number_of_zerosd\n",$subd);
```

to

```
$newstg = $newstg . sprintf("%0${number_of_zeros}d\n",$subd); 
#                             __^             __^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$newstg * ( 10 ** $number_of_zeroes )
```

or

```
$newstg . ( '0' x $number_of_zeroes )
```